# ubuntu-cleaner in 14.04LTS?

Tags: python

Running 14.04LTS on a 32bit laptop.  Installed same and trying to start from CLI but it returns the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-cleaner", line 15, in 
    from ubuntucleaner.settings.debug import enable_debugging

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntucleaner/settings/debug.py", line 6, in 
    from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Notify

ImportError: cannot import name Notify

What does this mean (and ubuntu-cleaner does not start)?

Comment: It means you need to file a bug report with the author on their github page. That's how you notify the author that their software is broken.

Comment: How did you get this executable? What is the output of `dpkg -S /usr/bin/ubuntu-cleaner` - is it installed from APT?

Comment: I'll investigate how to file a bug report - thanks

Comment: Output from dpkg -S /usr/bin/ubuntu-cleaner      ubuntu-cleaner:  /usr/bin/ubuntu-cleaner       From instructions on ubuntuhandbook.org, I installed ubuntu-cleaner using the following:     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gerardpuig/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-cleaner